# why callback variable is undefined in this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function which handle an Ajax call in my status.js:

```
window.APPLICATION = window.APPLICATION || {};
    window.APPLICATION = {
        getStatus: function(callingScope) {

                var _this = this;

                var getStatus = $.ajax({

                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/php/status.php",
                    data: {
                        "action": "mystatus"
                    }

                });

                getStatus.done(function(Response) {

                    if (Response.data != undefined) {
                        _this.cache.statusdata = {
                            userstatus: Response.data
                        };


                    } else if (Response.error != undefined) {
                        console.log('status data request error...');

                    }

                    callingScope.ajaxLoaded++;

                }),

                getStatus.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    console.log("user save form fail - an error occurred: (" + textStatus + ").");
                });

        },
    }
```

in my user.js, I call it:

```
window.APPLICATION.USER.ajaxLoaded = 0;
window.APPLICATION.getStatus(window.APPLICATION.USER);
```

I need this ajaxLoaded variable counter as I have other Ajax calls. Need it to determine whether all calls finished.

However, I got following errors in console:

[image]

how to solve it?

Comment: You probably have a typo in your actual code and don't pass the right value.

Comment: USER is undefined and you are attaching ajaxLoaded to user object which is undefined. That's why you are getting the error that callingScope is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.APPLICATION.USER.ajaxLoaded = 0;
```

this line is giving error.

It's because, `USER` is undefined.

You need to declare `USER` as an object first before defining properties.

so

```
window.APPLICATION.USER = {};
```

then

```
 window.APPLICATION.USER.ajaxLoaded = 0; // this will work
```

Inside the callback you are trying to access window.APPLICATION.USER object which was undefined so callingScope is giving error that it's undefined

Comment: The Chrome Javascript console would catch this and tell you were you went wrong.

Comment: That's not the error the OP is getting though. And if this was a problem, then `getStatus` would not even be executed. So, it's probably defined but the OP didn't show how.

Comment: callingScope represents the USER which is undefined. You are trying to access property of undefined

Comment: @Felix why getStatus will give you error?? You can pass undefined as argument

Comment: @mohamedrias - Yes, you can pass `undefined` as the `callingScope` parameter and that is not an error, but inside the `getStatus()` function it tries to use `callingScope` as an object and get one of its properties - that's when the error happens.

Comment: Of course you can. My point is that if `USER` is not defined, then `window.APPLICATION.USER.ajaxLoaded = 0;` will **throw an error** and the subsequent line `window.APPLICATION.getStatus(window.APPLICATION.USER);` **won't be executed**. And if `getStatus` is not executed, then OP cannot get the error he is talking about. So, the fact that `getStatus` is called tells us that `window.APPLICATION.USER` is probably defined. Makes sense?